# What is the data type for binary values? Is it string data type?

Tags: c#, binary, algebraic-data-types

What data type do binary (`1`'s and `0`'s) have? In one example I saw them as having string as a data type.

From that I know strings are not used for variables on which calculations are performed.

So when two binary variables have a data type as string and they have co be operated with each other, how would that be done?

Comment: I sense a lot of issues in the question itself. A single 0/1 is a boolean (false/true), several of them could either be stored in a BitArray or as a single bit in a Byte. Several bytes would require a byte-array (Byte[]). However, there are _no_ numeric (add, subtract, multiplication, division) operators available for you since it's just a bunch of bits, and there's no way for anyone to know if they are integers, single precision floats, or an number system yet to be invented. Code working with binary values in non-binary types (String) is bad.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a datatype "binary". There is one class that allows you to handle bits [BitVector32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32(v=vs.110).aspx)

Or you can simply convert the binary value from a `string` (text) to an `int`

```
//                           binary    , base
int binary = Convert.ToInt32("00000101", 2);
```

---

You could create a `Binary` class if you really want and then overload the operators, something like this:

```
public class Binary
{
    private int value;

    public Binary(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Binary(string b)
    {
        return new Binary(Convert.ToInt32(b, 2));
    }

    public static explicit operator int(Binary b)
    {
        return b.value;
    }

    public static Binary operator +(Binary a, Binary b)
    {
        return new Binary(a.value + b.value);
    }
}
```

And then have this

```
Binary bin1 = "0001"; // 1
Binary bin2 = "0010"; // 2

Binary result = bin1 + bin2; // 3

int integerResult = (int)result; // 3
```

Comment: and then use intergerResult in the program whenever I need the addition of those specific binariy values, right? each time we enter the binaries to be added Binary class and it does the calculations and converts the values back again in the binary form and gives us that, right?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarifications. When you've converted the binary value to a string, you've given up the direct ability to multiply since the values are no longer numeric (same reason that `string s = "3" * "4";` won't work either). You'd have to convert the values to a numeric data type to perform the mathematical operation, and then back to string for display.

```
string b1 = Convert.ToString(3, 2);
string b2 = Convert.ToString(4, 2);
string product = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(b1, 2) * Convert.ToInt32(b2, 2), 2);
Console.WriteLine(product); // 
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(product, 2));
```

Comment: what i mean is: eg. string binaryValue = ConvertToString(217,2); now we have converted an integer to its binary form which is saved in a string variable. Now lets say we have similarly another string value binaryValue2. Now both of these are binary representations of 2 integers. How would mathematical operations be performed on them if needed ?  eg. binaryValue * binaryValue2 . Why are they saved as strings when converting from integers? Can they have any other data type? If not, y?

Comment: Because you used ConvertToString.

Comment: ok. so what do I need to use to convert integers in their binary forms where computations can be performed on them?

Comment: Just updated answer based on your example. Thank you for the clarification - hope the answer is helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason. So we cannot have any other data type for binary other than string to perform direct calculations between them instead of converting them to int and then performing the computation and then converting back again?

Comment: Correct. You have to convert the values that are strings into some numerical type, and then back again when you are done with the calculations. If this is a backend-only thing, you could always convert the binary number from your data source straight to an integer, and leave the values as integer types so calculations can always be performed, then only convert the integers back to binary strings just before rendering your output.

Comment: Thanks Jason. So the way I understand is binaries cannot perform computations on each other directly. All data is stored at the hardware level in the form of binary. Wouldn't such data have to be manipulated by performing operations between each other? When this is required, they operations are performed indirectly?

Comment: Now you're getting into the low-level, machine code running in the hardware, and yes, that is all binary/mathematical operations. I am not a low-level developer - I usually stick in the C#/db world. My understanding is the high-level code we've been writing is compiled into an intermediate language as part of the .NET framework (so all .NET languages can compile and work together), and then the intermediate language is translated into an assembly-type language, and then machine code for execution on the hardware itself to run through the logic gates, gateways, and buses.